# Pi 4 - Connecting with eth0 but not with wlan0

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-4, dhcp

I am facing a issue in the last days. I have a LAMP server working 24/7 and connected with networks using wlan0.

About 2 months ago, i bought a 4G LTE router and used it. All fine, so i decided to try and use USB cable between 4G router - Pi. I was working better and using eth0. Now, I have noticed that i can connect to router using wlan0. If i remove the USB cable the Pi is not using the wlan0. If i reboot, it does the same. The only way is to attach the usb cable.

I have setup a script "keep-wifi-alive" which ping 8.8.8.8 and if it is down to reload wlan0.

I check `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd`
and noticed: `Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of dhcpcd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.`. I tried daemon-reload and reboot but no luck.

Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash

# keep wifi alive
ping -c2 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
  # restart wlan
  sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
    sleep 30
  sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
fi
```

Check my wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GR

#Home
network={
 ssid="Home"
 psk="Pass"
 priority=10
 id_str="Home"
}

#Home2
network={
 ssid="Home2"
 psk="Pass2"
 priority=9
 id_str="Home2"
}
```

My dhcpcd output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status dhcpcd
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of dhcpcd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-04-04 19:54:05 EEST; 20min ago
  Process: 471 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -w (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 801 (dhcpcd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           ├─582 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
           └─801 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w

Apr 04 19:53:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[471]: usb0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Apr 04 19:53:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[471]: usb0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr 04 19:54:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[471]: usb0: offered 192.168.0.125 from 192.168.0.1
Apr 04 19:54:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[471]: usb0: probing address 192.168.0.125/24
Apr 04 19:54:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[471]: usb0: leased 192.168.0.125 for 7200 seconds
Apr 04 19:54:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[471]: usb0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
Apr 04 19:54:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[471]: usb0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
Apr 04 19:54:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[471]: forked to background, child pid 801
Apr 04 19:54:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Apr 04 19:54:09 raspberrypi dhcpcd[801]: usb0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

Tried:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

Comment: Try using country code in wpa_supplicant in upper case (GR)

Comment: @Dirk I tried it but the same. I think the issue is in the last line above `wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface` and here `Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of dhcpcd.service...`

Comment: "decided to try and use USB cable between 4G router" presumably means you tried to use `dtoverlay=dwc2` (although WHY anyone would WANT to do this escapes me when there is an Ethernet interface). You will need to remove this. This Question is lacking any meaningful details or diagnostics. Fiddling with `ifconfig` or `wpa_supplicant` is only going to make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite wpa_supplicant.conf with nano and reboot. I don't know what it was.